# How to link react-native HOC dependencies?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-linking

I am using a React native HOC exported as a npm module which uses `@react-native-community/async-storage` internally throwing `AsyncStorage of null` due to linking issue. How do I link dependencies automatically once the module is installed?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "react-native-webview": "^5.12.1"
}
```

I wrote https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-sheet this library which uses `react-native-webview` as a dependency. When I am trying to use `react-native-google-sheet` I am getting linking an error as installing dependency wouldn't link the library. Is there a way to do that in my library which would link the dependency?

Update:
I see it's a bit confusing. Assume Mr. X using a module react-native-google-sheet in app.js which internally use react-native-webview which he might not be aware of. Mr. X am just an end user trying to use module but getting an error because it using a module which should be linked. Now as I developer of react-native-google-sheet I don't want the enduser to face that issue. So the question is there a way when Mr. X does yarn add react-native-google-sheet does react-native link react-native-webview after installing it? More of like 'postinstall` which react-native-google-sheet module would take care.

Answer (score 0):

**React Native 0.60+**

[CLI auto-link](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) feature links the module while building the app.

**React Native <= 0.59**

$ react-native link @react-native-community/async-storage
Note For iOS using cocoapods, run:

$ cd ios/ && pod install

**Upgrading to React Native 0.60+**

New React Native comes with autolinking feature, which automatically links Native Modules in your project. In order to get it to work, make sure you unlink Async Storage first:

$ react-native unlink @react-native-community/async-storage

Comment: Umm I am not sure if the question was a bit confusing, so wrote https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-sheet this library which uses `react-native-webview` as a dependency. When I am trying to use `react-native-google-sheet` I am getting linking an error as installing dependency wouldn't link the library. Is there a way to do that in my library which would link the dependency?

Comment: Try running :
`npm install --save react-native-webview`
                        
`react-native link react-native-webview`

Comment: Assume Mr. X using a module `react-native-google-sheet` in `app.js` which internally use `react-native-webview` which he might not be aware of. Mr. X am just an end user trying to use module but getting an error because it using a module which should be linked.
Now as I developer of  `react-native-google-sheet` I don't want the enduser to face that issue. So the question is there a way when Mr. X does `yarn add react-native-google-sheet` does `react-native link react-native-webview` after installing it? More of like 'postinstall` which `react-native-google-sheet` module would take care.